# Only accepting valid inputs in Java and outputting remainder

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement, while-loop, double

I'm trying to write code that takes valid input ($0.05, $0.10, $0.20, $0.50, $1.00, $2.00, $5.00, $10.00, $20.00, $50.00, $100.00) and outputs any remainder, with output code similar to:

```
    $38.00 remains to be paid. Insert money: $20.00
    You gave $20.00.
    $18.00 remains to be paid. Insert money: 3
    Invalid value. Try again.
    $18.00 remains to be paid. Insert money: $9
    Invalid value. Try again.
    $18.00 remains to be paid. Insert money: $10.00
    You gave $30.00
    $8.00 remains to be paid. Insert money: $8.00
    Invalid value. Try again.
```

Unfortunately at the moment, when I enter an integer like '3', it sometimes outputs "empty string" and sometimes outputs "Invalid value. Try again." but still takes the value of the integer as part of paidTotal i.e

```
    $18.00 remains to be paid. Insert money: $10.00
    You gave $10.00.
    $8.00 remains to be paid. Insert money: 4
    empty String
    $8.00 remains to be paid. Insert money: $2.00
    You gave $10.00.
    $8.00 remains to be paid. Insert money: 9
    empty String
    $8.00 remains to be paid. Insert money: 9
    Invalid value. Try again.
    $8.00 remains to be paid. Insert money: $5.00
    You gave $10.00.
    $8.00 remains to be paid. Insert money: $2.00
    You gave $12.00
    $6.00 remains to be paid. Insert money:
```

Here's the relevant section of my code. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
System.out.print("$" + formatter.format(priceSum) + " remains to be paid. Insert money: ");
String moneyEntered = keyboard.nextLine();
System.out.println("");
String noDollar = moneyEntered.substring(1);
double moneyAsDouble = Double.parseDouble(noDollar);
double paidTotal = 0;
paidTotal += moneyAsDouble;
List validMoney = Arrays.asList("$0.05", "$0.10", "$0.20", "$0.50", "$1.00", "$2.00", "$5.00", "$10.00", "$20.00", "$50.00", "$100.00");

boolean moneyEnteredFound = true;

while(true) {
    if (validMoney.contains(moneyEntered)) {
        while (paidTotal < priceSum) {
            if (validMoney.contains(moneyEntered)) {
                System.out.println("You gave $" + formatter.format(paidTotal));
                System.out.print("$" + formatter.format(priceSum - paidTotal) + " remains to be paid. Enter coin or note: ");
                moneyEntered = keyboard.nextLine();
                noDollar = moneyEntered.substring(1);
                moneyAsDouble = Double.parseDouble(noDollar);
                        paidTotal += moneyAsDouble;
            } else {
                System.out.println("Invalid value. Try again.");
                System.out.print("$" + formatter.format(priceSum - paidTotal) + " remains to be paid. Enter coin or note: ");
                moneyEntered = keyboard.nextLine();
            }
         }
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason that you are sometimes seeing "Empty String" is because for certain inputs you are not including the dollar sign. So `String noDollar = moneyEntered.substring(1);` skips the one and only character, and then you have the empty string. "Invalid value. Try again." occurs correctly when the dollar sign is included but the money value is not in the `ArrayList`.

You are also adding `moneyAsDouble` to `paidTotal` before you validate that `validMoney` contains `moneyEntered`. So whether or not the input was valid, the `double` value will be added to `paidTotal`. Further, within the while loop, you add `moneyAsDouble` to `paidTotal` again.

I think that there are multiple issues here that could be fixed. Go through the code step by step, and see what it does. You will see where your order is failing.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! If I leave `double paidTotal = 0`  and don't add `moneyAsDouble` to it however, then I get `"You gave $0.00"`. If you could give some guidance as to the structure of my loops, that would be amazing.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to treat input as numbers. In that case you simplify (a lot) the validations and in general, input handling.

The `Empty String` thing is showing because for sometimes you don't include the dollar sign when you type the values, and because `.substring(1)` returns a string that is a substring begining with the character at the specified index, in your case `1`, it skips that one and only one character. Additionally, you have some other details that you should take care of...I did some refactoring to your code, hope it helps :)

```
final Set<Double> VALID_INPUT = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(0.05, 0.10, 0.20, 0.50, 1.00,
    2.00, 5.00, 10.00, 20.00, 50.00, 100.00));
final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
//final double priceSum = 104.89d; // This should be a parameter or an input
double acc = 0.00d;

System.out.printf("$%.2f remains to be paid. Insert money: $", priceSum);

String input = scanner.nextLine();

while (acc < priceSum) {
  final Double amount = Double.valueOf(input); // TODO: Handle invalid format here

  // Uncomment the second one to avoid negative values (if not allowed)
  if (VALID_INPUT.contains(value)/* && (acc + amount < priceSum)*/) {
    acc += value;
    System.out.printf("You gave $%.2f%n", value);
  } else {
    System.out.println("Invalid value. Try again...");
  }
  System.out.printf("$%.2f remains to be paid. Enter coin or note: $", priceSum - acc);
  input = scanner.nextLine();
}
```

Comment: I've modified my code so it's similar to what you've given, but when I enter a valid input like '$5.00' I get "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot format given Object as a Number". Any ideas? Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: You only need to enter the amounts, without the `$` sign